# Recommendations for a Network Graph Builder

Tags: csv, networking, graph, export-to-excel

Some recommendations about a tool where you can visually build a network graph like the one below prior to export its nodes + links into csv format ?

[Network Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3b5U.png)

Comment: " visually build"  What do you mean by this?

Comment: Mainly clicking to add nodes, labelling them and draw links between them.

Comment: https://github.com/JamesBremner/graphex